# Ion-datetime how to open view on current year, but to not select day

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

i am working on an issue with a ionic date-time date picker.

When i open the datepicker, it opens with a view of may 2021.
when i scroll along to the current date, i see a circle around today's date. so it does seem to be selecting todays date correctly.

i have tried setting the value of today, and this works. however, it also selects the current date.

This is a problem.

I need the current month to open in the view, but for the datepicker to not have anything selected. I have read through the documentation and there doesn't seem to be an option for giving a initial view.

As far as i know, working with a 'New date' to isostring() solution wouldn't work either, as it would select the current date, and i can't leave parts of that iso string blank.

anyone have any ideas for this specific problem? it would seem so straightforward for there to be a view selector.

Comment: any news here? I've the same here right now

Answer (score 0):

I had to update "@ionic/angular-toolkit"

Comment: I'm on @ionic/angular-toolkit v7.0.0 which is the latest release and this problem still happens